# mvc images in css not loading in application virtual directory

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, iis

When I was debugging my site, all images and js were running with no issues.

Now I have set up my site as an application is in IIS.

So my url is now like

```
http://localhost/mysite
```

I am referencing my css file in my view as such

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Css/Default.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And in this css file I am adding my BG image as such

```
body
{
    background: url("/Images/bg.png");
    font-family: 'Oswald' , sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

But the image does not load it goes to a 404 with a path of `http://localhost/Images/bg.png,` when the path should be `http://localhost/mysite/Images/bg.png`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Remove the first slash, from  `background: url("/Images/bg.png");`

Comment: what if you try `background: url("Images/bg.png");` ?

Comment: That doesn't work...but this did     background: url("../Images/bg.png");

Comment: If you put a `/` before, then it will be relative to the root, which in this case is `localhost`, so it would appear as `localhost/images/my-image.jpg` - if you did want to use `/images/blah`, then you could set up a virtual host, like `somesite.dev` and it would work. Otherwise as you mentioned, you can do `../` to go up a directory, and then into the `images` folder.

Comment: I guess I am looking for something to work as path for the image to work no matter how the url is set up

Comment: It also depends if you put the site in the root directory e.g `www.mydomain.com`, or if it will be run from a subfolder e.g. `www.mydomain.com/somefolder/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, urls are relative to the location of the CSS file.

So you could simply reference your image like this:

```
background: url("../Images/bg.png");
```